# Insert ads within category, archive, tag & search page for WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements, adsense

I like to insert adsense in the middle of category, archive, tag & search page listing on a WordPress website. Here is the closest solution I can find online:

```
<?php $postcounter = 1;
if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : $postcounter = $postcounter + 1;
the_post(); ?>
<?php if(4 == $postcounter)
{ echo ' <div id="adsbetween">
<center> YOUR_ADSENSE_CODE </center>
</div> ' ;
} ?>
```

I need help on applying the same with what I have in my theme below:

```
if (($cat_layout == 'masonry-3') || ($cat_layout == 'masonry-2')) {
    echo '<div class="module-masonry-wrapper clear-fix">';
    echo '<div class="masonry-content-container">';

    while (have_posts()): the_post();
        echo kid_masonry_render(get_the_ID());
    endwhile;

    echo '</div></div>';
```

Here is another instance:

```
echo '<div class="classic-blog-content-container">';
while (have_posts()): the_post();
    echo kid_classic_blog_render(get_the_ID(), 35);
endwhile;
echo '</div>';
```

The code should ad ADSENSE_CODE after the 4th listing.

Any help?

Comment: Try remove `$postcounter = $postcounter + 1;` and put `$postcounter++;` before `endwhile;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should inject the adsense and let the loop continue (I think that is what you want).

```
if($cat_layout=='masonry-3' || $cat_layout=='masonry-2'){
    $postcounter=1;
    echo '<div class="module-masonry-wrapper clear-fix">';
        echo '<div class="masonry-content-container">';
            while(have_posts()){
                if($postcounter==4){
                    echo '<div id="adsbetween"><center>YOUR_ADSENSE_CODE</center></div>';
                }
                the_post();
                echo kid_masonry_render(get_the_ID());
                ++$postcounter;
            }
        echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

---

The extra case:

```
$postcounter=1;
echo '<div class="classic-blog-content-container">';
    while(have_posts()){
        if($postcounter==4){
            echo '<div id="adsbetween"><center>YOUR_ADSENSE_CODE</center></div>';
        }
        the_post();
        echo kid_classic_blog_render(get_the_ID(),35);
        ++$postcounter;
    }
echo '</div>';'
```

Comment: *note, if you have fewer than 4 posts, adsense won't appear.  Is this a concern?

Comment: It is not a concern, what about in a case like this: 'echo '<div class="classic-blog-content-container">';
                        while (have_posts()): the_post();
                        echo kid_classic_blog_render(get_the_ID(), 35);
                        endwhile;
                    echo '</div>';'